# how call a function with in the class in djagno shell

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

```
class Test:
    def m1():
        pass
    def m2():
        pass
```

I have this class in the test.py(Django-Project) file how to call the m2 function in Django. shell. how to call this function in Django shell.

I am trying like this:

```
>> python manage.py shell
>> from appname.filename import <class_name|function_name>
```

But it thrown an error like this: *ImportError: cannot import name <class_name|function_name>*. anyone help me out with this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to import the class from the module and not the function in the class. Something like this might work.

```
# myfile.py

class TestClass:
    def func1():
        pass
```

```
from myfile import TestClass

test_class = TestClass()
test_class.func1()
```